How to split tar archive on files matching pattern?
Suppose I have a large sample.tar with content:
foo/...
bar/...
baz/...
...

How to split in two disjoint tarballs so that one archive will contain files matching the pattern and the other archive rest?
Attempt
Looking at --delete in GNU tar the idea was to make 2 copies and delete corresponding parts. This side works perfectly:
tar -vf sample.tar --delete --wildcards 'foo/*' 'bar/*'

How to negate the selection? It seems that --delete doesn't play well with --exclude as neither of the following works (removes everything):
tar -vf sample.tar --delete --wildcards '*' --exclude='foo/*' --exclude='bar/*'
tar -vf sample.tar --delete --wildcards --exclude='foo/*' --exclude='bar/*' '*'

Notes

I don't want to re-pack the archive in order to preserve all attributes (user IDs, setuid bit, timestamps etc...)
I don't want to use extra tools which are not part of standard distribution (apt install from default repository is ok, compiling from sources no)
I can imagine poor man's approach by listing the content using tar -t ... and generating arguments for negated selection but hope there is a better way
Above experiments done w/ GNU tar 1.34

